# set or add value to pandas cell // optimisation

Tags: python, pandas

Provided a string like `XYZ` I need to set a value in a pandas cell or append it depending on the cell being empty or not.
If the cell is empty the value is set to `XYZ` if the cell is not empty then I add it preceding it by `;`, for instance the result would be `notempty;XYZ`

How do I do it?
assuming a dataframe:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'D':['a','b','','c'],
                'E':['d','','','']})

# I would like to add the string:
mystring='XYZ'
condition = (dff['E'] == 'd')

# checking if he cell where I want to add is empty or not
if dff.loc[condition,['D']]['D'][0] == '':
    dff.loc[condition,['D']] = mystring
else: 
    # the cell is not empty. Hence I have to add ; and the string
    content = dff.loc[condition,['D']]['D'][0]
    dff.loc[condition,['D']] = content + ';' + mystring
```

The question is.
This is not pythonic-nice at all.
Any suggestion?

Note1: I added that condition because in reality I have plenty of them and I can not use 
pd.at, which might be tempting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'D':['a','b','','c'],
                'E':['d','','','']})

mystring='XYZ'

dff["D"] = np.where(dff["D"]=="",mystring,dff["D"]+";"+mystring)

print (dff)

       D  E
0  a;XYZ  d
1  b;XYZ   
2    XYZ   
3  c;XYZ
```